# Actionscript 3 replacing string

Tags: string, actionscript-3, actionscript

I am trying to replace a substring in a string. My code below replaces all occurrences of substring. E.g. When clicked on **in** it replaces both **in**. But I like to replace only clicked one. How can we do this?

The books are **in** the table **in** my room.

```
          function correct(e:TextEvent):void{
                str =String(e.currentTarget.htmlText);
                if(e.text==replacements[e.currentTarget.name]){
                    e.currentTarget.htmlText =strReplace(str, e.text,    corrections[e.currentTarget.name]);
                }
        }


         function strReplace(str:String, search:String, replace:String):String {
             return str.split(search).join(replace);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TextField.getCharIndexAtPoint(x:Number, y:Number):int` to get the (0-based) index of the char in a particular coordinate.

You obviously need to use your clicked point as *(x, y)*.

You can use `localX` and `localY` from `TextField.click` event.

See here for more: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#getCharIndexAtPoint%28%29

At this point you need to search the string to replace in the neighborhood of the clicked char.

For example, something like this:

```
stringToReplace = "in";

len = stringToReplace.Length;

neighborhood = TextField.substring(clickedCharIndex-len, clickedCharIndex+len);

if (neighborhood.indexOf(stringToReplace)) {

    neighborhood = neighborhood.replace(stringToReplace, replacement);

    TextField.text = TextField.text(0, clickedCharIndex-len) + neighborhood +
                     TextField.text(clickedCharIndex+len);

}
```